Can not use zero_copy with u8 primitive type
I have this struct:
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[derive(bytemuck::Zeroable)]
#[derive(bytemuck::Pod)]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct BitSet(u8);

It is used in:
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
#[zero_copy(unsafe)]
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct Invocation {
    /// The stack heights from where the margin program invoked an adapter.
    caller_heights: BitSet,
}

But bytemuck errors with #[zero_copy]function or associated item not found in BitSet.
Same if I will use it in the upper struct with #[zero_copy(unsafe)].
I am using bytemuck = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["derive", "min_const_generics"]}.

Your question is missing a few details to provide a precise answer:

What version of Anchor are you using?
What version of Rust are you using and/or Solana sdk/cli?
What is the full error you get in the terminal when trying to build?
What command are you running when you get the error?

I suppose that you are using the latest Anchor to date (0.30.x) and that you get the error when using the command anchor build but not when you run cargo build. My guess is that you encounter an error related to the new Anchor method used to generate IDLs.
At the moment you are deriving manually Pod and Zeroable on BitSet instead of using the macro zero_copy. Because of this, the type BitSet is missing some trait implementations required by Anchor to generate the IDL. In general you should be able to solve this issue by simply replacing the manual bytemuck derives with #[zero_copy].
However, I'd like to point to other potential issues with your code:

IDL usually don't like tuple-struct like BitSet and it is preferred to have named field in your structures. However, maybe you could work around these thanks to the new IDL generation method by either implementing the IDL traits yourself or using feature flags to make a difference between a struct for the IDL (directly using u8) and the one you actually want to use in your code (BitSet)
When using zero_copy you need to think about alignment. For better portability and support of future version of rust you should ensure that all the structure fields are aligned to 128 bits and all your structure sizes are multiple of 128 bits. A struct just composed of one u8 might be fine depending on how and where you use it but the rule of thumb is to always add explicit padding to follow the most restrictive alignment and size constraints (128 bits or 16 bytes).
Avoid zero_copy(unsafe) at all cost.


Thanks a lot man!!! Best!!!
